# Is there a way for a user to verify themselves when following a checksum link?

Tags: email, security

Use case:

1. Email a checksum link to a user asking them to update their profile data.
2. When that user clicks the checksum link, request that they fill out a couple of verification fields such as postcode/date of birth/account number before being shown their data (just in case its not them).

I saw this demo'd at CiviCon London 2014 but can't remember who presented it, what it was called or if it was already part of CiviCRM or an extension. Googling for it has been unsuccessful.

Comment: Would be good to see the answer come forth. We have in past provided a 'read only' profile showing eg Name and then provide a 'confirm this is me' field etc. But it isn't actually doing verification that they know other 'hidden' data about themselves. It was more as a 'how to stop Mary overwriting John's details' quick fix. It also required a 'session' be opened so the checksum worked beyond the first profile.

Comment: This feature would be quite useful - here's a page with a spec (from 2012) which would allow anon. users to confirm their profile: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Allowing+anonymous+users+to+see+and+edit+their+existing+Profile+form+data - how can I find/get hold of this profile

Answer (score 1):

I dont remember this session at CiviCon London. By any chance, are you referring to the email address validation on unsubscribe (the user has to enter their email address to unsubscribe)

I suspect the way the above would need to be done, would be:

a. Take the user to a different validate and confirmation page.

b. On confirmation, send the user to the real profile edit page

c. Add a hook to the profile edit page to ensure that any user coming here  has come via the confirmation page

Comment: The functionality I saw a demo of wasn't for validating the email address on subscribe/unsubscribe.

The steps you have described are what I saw demo'd.

Comment: you can check the schedule here: https://london2014.civicrm.org/sessions and see if that jogs up your memory as to which session it was

Comment: I checked through the schedule and watched a few of the videos but didn't come across it.  Someone somewhere knows about this feature and it'll probably turn up again at some point!

Answer (score 1):

roxca, et al - could this be what you're looking for?
It is from back in Oct. 2010 : http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=16030.0
Source code is here: https://app.box.com/shared/dsti564nkn

Comment: nice find ;-) though I expect it has a thick layer of dust on it - would have been a good addition to core but apparently didn't get the additional support to make that happen

Comment: Yeah, it has (dust) - the package also isn't put together as an 'extension' w/an info.xml, *civix.php, etc. but the gist is the dialog box and code to send a link to user profile page w/checksum; sounds like you know of something more robust/standard that Eileen McN. created

Comment: I don't recall if we (Fuzion inc. Eileen) ever got to rejig the work that Alric (AJA) did. It sounds possible but not finding any record of it. If i had to start from scratch, on Drupal, I might go this way Create a new Activity Type. Set up a webform-civicrm with just an email field and the above Activity. Then use Scheduled Reminder set to 0 hours to fire out the email with a checksum. Sounds tedious though. CiviRules might be able to cut out a step or two. But that is still not what the original question was after.